# Is there a radar - like sensor that can tell me the distances of multiple things around the sensor?

Tags: sensors

I'm trying to develop something that requires accurate distance measurement of objects around the center of the contraption. However, I cannot find any way to achieve this other than using a bunch of infrared distance sensors. Really, I'm looking for something that costs at most $200 and is compatible either with arduino, PC, or raspberry pi.

This may not be the place for this, if not, please inform me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If seen people put an ultrasonic sensor on a serve. By moving the servo you can "scan" the surroundings. It is however a bit slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [**lidar**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) - but it's not cheap. [RPLIDAR](http://rplidar.robopeak.com/) is the current price leader for non-hacky solutions, and I haven't seen it for much less than $400 anywhere.

Comment: Wait so would you suggest just using the infrared distance sensors then?

Comment: I don't know your application, so I can't answer that.